# How to calculate the winner and loser when with dice in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, random, dice

I have set up two separate "games" where two dice go at random and it calculates the score for both. What i can't do is show the "winner" and the "loser". So theres player 1 and player 2, and what i want to do is write winner or loser below the player with the highest or lowest score. I tried calculating it myself using javascript but none of the code i find is correct.I have searched everywhere online but nothing seems to be working so i don't know what i am doing wrong also i am sorry for this being so long i am in dire need as everything i am doing isn't working, the code i have here is just the dices and the score but with no "winner" or "looser"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <script> 

    var randomNumber1 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;
    var opentag = " <img src = 'die";
    var closetag = ".gif'>";
    var imageTagString1 = opentag + randomNumber1 + closetag;
    var imageTagString2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    var imageTagString2 = " <img src = \"die" + randomNumber2 + ".gif\">";
    var score = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;

    document.write ("<p>The Score is : " + score);
    document.write(imageTagString1);
    document.write(imageTagString2);

    </script>
</div>
<div>
    <script> 

    var randomNumberA = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;
    var randomNumberB = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;
    var opentag = " <img src = 'die";
    var closetag = ".gif'>";
    var imageTagString1 = opentag + randomNumberA + closetag;
    var imageTagString2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    var imageTagString2 = " <img src = \"die" + randomNumberB + ".gif\">";
    var score2 = randomNumberA + randomNumberB;

    document.write ("<p>The Score is : " + score);
    document.write(imageTagString1);
    document.write(imageTagString2);

    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, shouldn't your "var closetag = ".gif'>"; be "var closetag = ".gif'/>"; And there seem to be some other small issues, mind setting up a fiddle or something?

Comment: @Sayuri This appears to be html5, so the close tag would be correct.  I'm more interested in what OP tried to determine the winner and loser, since there appears to be no comparisons in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have images die1.gif to die6.gif in the same directory as the html file, the following code should be fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script type ='text/javascript'> 
        var player1Dice1 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;
        var player1Dice2 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;

        var player2Dice1 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;
        var player2Dice2 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;

        var scoreP1 = player1Dice1 + player1Dice2;
        var scoreP2 = player2Dice1 + player2Dice2;

        var opentag = " <img src = 'die";
        var closetag = ".gif'>";

        var p1d1 = opentag + player1Dice1 + closetag;
        var p1d2 = opentag + player1Dice2 + closetag;

        var p2d1 = opentag + player2Dice1 + closetag;
        var p2d2 = opentag + player2Dice2 + closetag;




        document.write ("<p>Player 1 score is : " + scoreP1);
        document.write(p1d1);
        document.write(p1d2);
        document.write ("<p>Player 2 score is : " + scoreP2);
        document.write(p2d1);
        document.write(p2d2);
        if (scoreP1 > scoreP2) {
            document.write("<p>Player 1 wins. Player 2 loses.</p>");
        }
        else if (scoreP2 > scoreP1) {
            document.write("<p>Player 2 wins. Player 1 loses.</p>");
        }
        else {
            document.write("<p>Draw.</p>"); 
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: ok thanks so much, i am guessing you do the same for the loser? or how do you do the loser?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: i want to show who is the "winner" and who is the "loser"

Comment: In the above code, if the game is not a draw, then if Player 1 wins, Player 2 is the loser and vice versa. I've edited the answer. Check it now.